# Loud pop after light switch changed

Tags: electrical

Garage light switch changed by father in law. Went into house turned on breaker. He said he heard a loud pop in garage after I flipped it for him, ENTIRE garage without power. No outlets work or anything. Breaker is still on, not tripped…  Help!!

Comment: 1. Turn the breaker off.

Comment: Ensure no other breakers are tripped. And possibly some wiring has vapourised.

Comment: With respect, if you don't know how to safely diagnose errors in your own work, you should call an electrician.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add pics of the inside of the box with the new switch. Make sure the breaker is *switched off*, and pull the switch out of the box so we can see all the wiring & where it goes.

Comment: Did you take pictures of the wire positions before you started?

Comment: *Breaker is still on, not tripped* Are you sure? Many breakers will trip without the handle actually flipping, by design. Take a picture of the wires on the switch. Disconnect all wires going to the switch and tape/cap them for safety. Turn the breaker off/on. If that gets everything else working then the problem is a bad switch or, more likely, the way you wired up the switch.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Correct sequence of operations there is Turn the breaker off, then inspect and disconnect. It might be tripped, or it might have used a bit of wire as a fuse and still be live, which would be bad if you had not turned the breaker off *before* disconnecting wires...

Comment: Check for GFCI outlets in the garage. One might have tripped .

Answer (score 1):

If the work is not being done **by the owner that lives in the house** or under **direct supervision of the owner**, you need a licensed electrician, not a "helpful" father-in-law (or "handyman" or "day laborer" or other unlicensed person) operating without following the direct orders and under the direct supervision of the owner of the house - unless they happen to be a licensed electrician, which seems unlikely, here.

That's the way the "homeowners can do their own electrical in single-family housing" *exception* works, where it applies at all (in some places and in occupancies other than owner-occupied single family homes, a licensed electrician is required regardless, due to the risk imposed on **others** by unlicensed work.)